# How to compare cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to compare the cells in column C with the cells in column D, and have column E say "OK" if the cells are the same and "Not OK" if they are not the same.

Comment: pls rearrange...can't see images...

Comment: Are comparing cells using some programming language or you want to compare them in excel itself?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps

```
=IF(EXACT(C1,D1),"OK", "Not OK")
```

Answer (score 0):

You use [`=IF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/if-function-HP010342586.aspx) to do what you want.

Comment: Thanx david and lennart

But i have One Problem in this formula when I campare "A" and "a" it says OK but i also need in this scenario it need to says NOt OK, I mean  

A and A    Ok
a and A    Not Ok
a and a    ok

Comment: OK, that was not comprehensible from your original question. Mark has the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is in C1 and D1, then in E1 enter "=IF(C1 = D1, "OK", "Not OK")"

Comment: That is how I'd do it too

Comment: Thanx david and lennart

But i have One Problem in this formula when I campare "A" and "a" it says OK but i also need in this scenario it need to says NOt OK, I mean  

A and A    Ok
a and A    Not Ok
a and a    ok

Comment: Yep, use Mark's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
=IF(EXACT(A1,B1),"OK","Not OK")
```